# Should we Copy Yarn cache inside a Docker Container?

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I read [a docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/keep-nodejs-rockin-in-docker/#dealing-with-node-modules) post that advises to re-run npm install when building a docker container because node_modules may contain binaries compiled for your host OS, and if it’s different then the container OS, you’ll get errors trying to run your app when you’re bind-mounting it from the host for development.

Yarn documentation states we should keep `yarn.lock`, `yarn/cache`, `yarn/plugins` and `yarn/release` folder checked-into the repo. This is how my Dockerfile looks:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-slim
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn set version 2.4.1

RUN yarn install

USER node

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

Following above blog's advice, should one ignore `.yarn` folder or not?

Comment: The container image should be as small as possible and so I would suggest not.

Comment: When copying cache dir: size: 182 MB, Build time: 37s
When not copying cache dir: size: 191 MB, Build time: 200+s
This is a little unexpected :( @RamanSailopal